# Duplicated cards in verticalGridView

Tags: java, android, android-tv, leanback

I have a strange problem here.

Context:

I'm building an Android TV application which makes use of Android's Leanback Library. When the user navigates to a show, it has a vertical grid view which lists all the episodes of the show.

The list is filled using an `ArrayObjectAdapter` to which I pass the `episodeModel` for each episode in the list and then I just set the adapter to the view using `setAdapter(adapter)` So far so good.

The thing is that when the user scrolls down the list the items that are not visible in the viewport gets updated but with the images and titles of those that were already passed. I mean, They looks like duplicated items but what's really going on is that the last items don't get updated with its own images and titles but with the ones of the first ones.

How do I prevent this to happen?

Here is the CardPresenter

```
public class CardPresenter extends Presenter {
    private static final String TAG = CardPresenter.class.getSimpleName();

    private static final int CARD_WIDTH = 420;
    private static final int CARD_HEIGHT= 236;
    private static int selectedBgColor;
    private static int defaultBgColor;
    private Drawable defaultCardimage;
    private ImageCardView mCardView;

    static class ViewHolder extends Presenter.ViewHolder{
        ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
        }
    }

    private static void updateCardBGColor(ImageCardView view, boolean selected){
        int color = selected ? selectedBgColor : defaultBgColor;
        view.setBackgroundColor(color);
        view.findViewById(R.id.info_field).setBackgroundColor(color);
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent) {
        defaultBgColor = ContextCompat.getColor(parent.getContext(), R.color.le_gray);
        selectedBgColor = ContextCompat.getColor(parent.getContext(), R.color.le_black);

        defaultCardimage = ContextCompat.getDrawable(parent.getContext(), R.drawable.default_bg);

        mCardView = new ImageCardView(parent.getContext()) {
            @Override
            public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
                super.setSelected(selected);
                updateCardBGColor(this, selected);
            }
        };
        mCardView.setMainImage(defaultCardimage);
        mCardView.setFocusable(true);
        mCardView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        mCardView.setCardType(BaseCardView.CARD_TYPE_INFO_UNDER);

        return new ViewHolder(mCardView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(Presenter.ViewHolder viewHolder, Object item) {
        if(item instanceof ShowModel){
            ShowModel showModel = (ShowModel) item;
            if(showModel.getThumbnail() != null){
                mCardView.setTitleText(showModel.getName());
                mCardView.setContentText(showModel.getType());
                mCardView.setMainImageDimensions(CARD_WIDTH, CARD_HEIGHT);
                Glide.with(viewHolder.view.getContext()).load(showModel.getThumbnail()).error(defaultCardimage).into(mCardView.getMainImageView());
            }
        }else if(item instanceof EpisodeModel){
            EpisodeModel episodeModel = (EpisodeModel) item;
            if(episodeModel.getStill() != null){
                mCardView.setTitleText(episodeModel.getTitle());
                mCardView.setContentText(episodeModel.getDescription());
                mCardView.setMainImageDimensions(CARD_WIDTH, CARD_HEIGHT);
                Glide.with(viewHolder.view.getContext()).load(episodeModel.getStill()).error(defaultCardimage).into(mCardView.getMainImageView());
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUnbindViewHolder(Presenter.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
        mCardView.setBadgeImage(null);
        mCardView.setMainImage(null);
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: This sounds like a problem with the (re)binding of the views that are being recycled. Can you share the code for where you're setting the titles, images, etc.?

Comment: Sure @IanG.Clifton, I've just updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update onBindViewHolder to use the ViewHolder to update the views. Right now you're creating a reference to whichever ImageCardView was most recently created and then updating it. For example, you have

```
mCardView.setTitleText(showModel.getName());
```

But the mCardView is not necessarily for the right position. You need to do something like this:

```
viewHolder.itemView.setTitleText(showModel.getName());
```

You may need to cast the itemView to an ImageCardView.